# Django orm MTM through filtering bug

Tags: python, django, orm

I have two models:

```
class Training(models.Model):
    statuses = models.ManyToManyField('company.Company',
                                      through='TrainingStatus')

class TrainingStatus(models.Model):
    training = models.ForeignKey('Training', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey('company.Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = FSMField(default=TrainingStatusStates.NEW,
                     choices=TrainingStatusStates.choices)
```

When I do query like this:

```
trainings = Training.objects.filter(trainingstatus__state='new')
if not self.request.user.is_superuser:
   trainings = trainings.filter(trainingstatus__company__id=3016)
```

I expected to see my `queryset` filter training by `trainingstatus` that have state `new` and `company_id=3016`

What I see:

```
SELECT `user_management_training`.`id` FROM `user_management_training` 
INNER JOIN `user_management_trainingstatus` ON (`user_management_training`.`id` = `user_management_trainingstatus`.`training_id`) 
INNER JOIN `user_management_trainingstatus` T3 ON (`user_management_training`.`id` = T3.`training_id`) 
WHERE (`user_management_trainingstatus`.`state` = new AND T3.`company_id` = 3016)
```

I get incorrect results because **filtering applying two times to whole trainingstatus queryset**

But If I modify my code to this:

```
trainings = Training.objects.filter(trainingstatus__state='new')
if not self.request.user.is_superuser:
   trainings = trainings.filter(trainingstatus__state='new',
                                trainingstatus__company=3016)
```

It works like expected.

Python 3.7
Django 1.11

Comment: If you use two different `filter`s then these are independent JOINs, this is not a bug, this is sometimes wanted behavior.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem hm, thanks. Can you provide an example for this case ?

Comment: if you for example want to filter on objects that both have as status `new` and `old`, you can filter with `Training.objects.filter(trainingstatus__state='new').filter(trainingstatus__state='old')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get incorrect results because filtering applying two times to whole trainingstatus queryset.

**No**. If you use two different `.filter(…)`s, then these are *independent* filters, so the JOINs are done differently.

You can define such behavior with `Q` objects:

```
from django.db.models import Q

q = Q(trainingstatus__state='new')
if not self.request.user.is_superuser:
   q &= Q(trainingstatus__company__id=3016)
trainings = Training.objects.filter(q)
```